# FIFA World Cups History: Defending Champion Knocked Out in First Round?

Tags: football, trivia, history, world-cup

As you all might have seen on 18th June, 2014 that **Spain**, winner of Last **FIFA World Cup 2010** was knocked out in first round. I need to know that is it happened first time or it did happen in any past World Cup? If yes, then when and which team?

I don't know much about previous FIFA World Cups.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**6** times the defending champions were knocked out of the group stage *(first group stage during the 1950 World Cup)* in the FIFA World Cup history:

- [Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy_at_the_FIFA_World_Cup) - [1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_at_the_FIFA_World_Cup) - [1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_at_the_FIFA_World_Cup) - [2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [Italy - 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain_at_the_FIFA_World_Cup) - [2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany_at_the_FIFA_World_Cup) - [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup)

References:

- [1](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/worldcup2014/article-2661795/Spain-fourth-World-Cup-holders-crash-group-stage-Brazil-France-Italy.html?ico=sport%5Eheadlines), [2](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/defending-champion-germany-eliminated-from-world-cup/2018/06/27/bd06b660-7a25-11e8-ac4e-421ef7165923_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.403c0f1da827)
- Wikipedia: [List of FIFA World Cup records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_records#Defending_champion_2) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_records&oldid=847766262#Defending_champion_2))

Comment: It should be noted that in 1950, Italy were defending champion because of winning the 1938 world cup (none was held in '42 and '46), so probably fewer of the winning team were there to defend the title, and that only the first round group winners advanced then (Italy came second in a group of 3).